# Can't make JSVGCanvas from Batik work in a Maven project

Tags: java, swing, maven, svg, batik

I spent 7h trying to make JSVGCanvas from Batik display a simple svg file. I can't make it work. The funny thing is that I always get different error messages given the versions of the dependencies I'm using. My last try gave me that :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation.createCSSEngine(Lorg/apache/batik/dom/svg/SVGOMDocument;Lorg/apache/batik/css/engine/CSSContext;)Lorg/apache/batik/css/engine/CSSEngine;
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext.initializeDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.swing.svg.GVTTreeBuilder.run(Unknown Source)
```

and also sometimes :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/gvt/event/AbstractAWTEventDispatcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.batik.gvt.event.AbstractAWTEventDispatcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

But I already saw thousands of these errors, always about noSuchMethodException, or ClassNotFoundException, but it happens inside the batik classes and I don't succeed to attach the source so I can't even try to debug it...

My code is pretty simple :

```
public class Test {
    private static JFrame mainFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainFrame = new JFrame("test");
                mainFrame.setSize(800,600);
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);

                Container pane = mainFrame.getContentPane();
                pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                JSVGCanvas canvas = new JSVGCanvas();
                canvas.setURI("file:///home/floz/NetBeansProjects/test/test.svg");
                pane.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code runs fine with normal dependencies, but if I use a Maven project it doesn't work. I tried to load the local jar, but I didn't get better results. Am I alone in this situation ?

Maven for batik : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics

EDIT: I discovered that it works only if the dependancies respect a specific folder hierarchy. I didn't even knew it could make a difference as they all are imported... Anymay, I'm stuck because I don't know how to create a hierarchy with Maven... Any idea ?

EDIT2: I discovered [svgSalamander](https://svgsalamander.java.net/) that quickly fixed my problem for displaying svg. It's much lighter than JSVGCanvas

Answer (score 1):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` is likely because one of the batik jars is not in your `classpath`.

Here's one way to fix that in Maven:

1. List the batik dependencies in pom.xml (assuming you have already done so)
2. Add the following plugin to pom.xml

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
          <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The `addClasspath` lines tells Maven to add your dependencies to the `classpath` in the main manifest file in the jar it generates.

The `mainClass` line needs to delineate your main class.

The `classpathPrefix` tells Maven to add `dependency/` to the front of the names of your dependencies' jars that it is putting on the classpath.

3. Run `mvn package` to generate your jar. Maven will place it in `./target`
4. Run `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`. This will cause Maven to download all of the dependencies' jar and place them in `./target/dependency`, which is were the `classpathPrefix` was configured to look.
5. `java -jar ./target/whatever-your-jar-is-names.jar` should then run properly.